# How to Delete COMPLETELY Blank Rows VBA

Tags: excel, vba, rows, delete-row

In my macro, I want to delete completely blank Rows. Not Rows that has something in one column because that is still valuable information.

I have looked all over the internet but if someone could come up with a function that deletes ENTIRELY blank rows and not just rows with something missing in a few columns that would be awesome.

(Information is only on Columns A through N and roughly 7 thousand rows). I haven't developed any code for this because I am really stumped.

Comment: Where is the data? Is it a file, a table in a database, Excel sheet?

Comment: What does your code currently look like? What have you tried?

Comment: What about the last million or so *completely* blank rows? Also, define "blank" -- **does formatting count?**  How many columns might be populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this...

```
Sub ClearEmptyRows()
  Dim r As Long, lastrow As Long, WS As Worksheet, killRng As Range

Set WS = ActiveSheet

lastrow = WS.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Set killRng = WS.Rows(Rows.Count)

For r = 1 To lastrow
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(WS.Rows(r)) = 0 Then
        Set killRng = Union(killRng, WS.Rows(r))
    End If

Next r

killRng.Delete

End Sub
```

A couple comments on this code for newbies as it's a common routine to loop through rows and do *something* (delete, highlight, hide, etc.)

- It's always best to interact with Worksheet as infrequently as possible. Thus we execute the `Delete` AFTER all of the rows have been identified.
- You can't `Union` an empty range, so I set the `killRng` to initially be the entire last row (hopefully this is always blank), and then the macro can proceed with `Union`. One could get around this by including an if-statement, but this requires the macro check if range exists on each row.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove empty rows and are not concerned about formatting this is super fast.

```
Sub RemoveEmptyRows()
    Dim results As Variant, Target As Range
    Dim c As Long, r As Long, n As Long
    Set Target = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

    If Target.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim results(1 To Target.Rows.Count, 1 To Target.Columns.Count)
        For r = 1 To Target.Rows.Count
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Target.Rows(r)) > 0 Then
                For c = 1 To Target.Columns.Count
                    n = n + 1
                    results(n, c) = Target.Cells(r, c).Value
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Target.Value = results
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```